# Monospace Font - Not really Monospace?

Tags: javascript, fonts, text-editor, monospace

This appears to be a bug that I've found using **JavaScript** in Gedit (when you change the font from "Ubuntu mono" to "Monospace") and Geany so far. I have a right margin set to 80 chars, but when I type `Object`, `prototype` or any other **key word** bolded by the program, It adds some letter spacing that throws off the spacing just slightly.

Because of this, I have a line declaring `Object` that's 79 characters, but appears to be 81.5 characters. Can someone advise me on how to fix this? Is it a Text Editor setting? Is it an issue with the font itself?

Comment: It's probably because your default monospace font doesn't have a native bold style. Just change the font. I'd suggest since you're in Linux, DejaVu Sans Mono or Liberation Mono; they'll work just fine.

Comment: That was exactly it. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it. Also, you'd think monospace would have a native bold style by now. There's no way I'm the first person to notice that the font named "monospace" has this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because your default monospace font doesn't have a native bold style. Just change the font. I'd suggest since you're in Linux, DejaVu Sans Mono or Liberation Mono; they'll work just fine.

> Also, you'd think monospace would have a native bold style by now

If you're in Ubuntu you can download [Unsettings](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/unsettings/) and change the default monospace font so when you open programs that have "monospace" as font it'll be the one you chose.

Btw, this is not unique to Linux. Check out the default monospace font on a Windows `cmd`...

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing font didn't help. The solution was to select option `Insert spaces instead of tabs` in the Preferences/Editor.