# Why are iOS Monospaced fonts not behaving like that?

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, kerning, monospace

I am using SpriteKit and have a timer in my iOS app rendered through an SKLabelNode and which is updated in the update function. I didn't want the digits moving left and right as the count increased, so I tried using Courier New. It worked much better than Avenir, but there are still subtle fluctuations in the width of some of the digits. (The 6 and the 9 are slightly wider than the other digits.) I saw these fluctuations in several different experiments where I tried:

- normal & bold styles
- large (65) & small (9) font sizes
- Courier New & Menlo fonts
- Xcode simulator & iPod Touch

I submitted queries like "which font has uniform width digits", but all the  answers I could find just say "use a monospaced font". (See https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13148/which-fonts-have-the-same-width-for-every-character or [Monospace Font - Not really Monospace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515185/monospace-font-not-really-monospace))

My code is super simple. I setup the scoreNode once like this:

```
    scoreNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Courier New")
    scoreNode.fontSize = 65
    scoreNode.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    scoreNode.text = "0"
    scoreNode.position = CGPoint(x: patternPane.midX, y: patternPane.midY)
    patternPaneNode.addChild(scoreNode)
```

And then I update the score like this:

```
    scoreNode.text = "\(viewControllerDelegate!.getScore())"
```

Here's an image overlaying the frame showing 28 with part of the frame showing 29. You can see that the edges of the movie are lined up and you can see that the base of the 2s do not line up.

[image: partial 29 overlaid on 28]

Any explanations?

Is it possible that iOS is applying kerning to the SKLabelNode even though I'm using a monospace font?

Comment: could you also add a screenshot?

Comment: Is that *one* SKLabelNote (displaying a two-digit number) or *two* nodes displaying one digit each? In the latter case, how is their position to each other defined?

Comment: It's one node with 2 digits.

Comment: I faced into the same problem; Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 9, all fonts use proportional numbers by default.

If you're using `UILabel`, you can [opt into monospaced digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854690/how-to-get-monospaced-numbers-in-uilabel-on-ios-9), but there isn't a solution for `SKLabelNode`, as far as I can tell.

More info in this WWDC2015 video (minute 26): https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/804/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and killed multiple days trying to solve it.
Here is my solution:

So, first of all - the function that sets the score. It uses `attributedText` instead of just `text`. That made possible use of `UIFont.monospacedSystemFont()`

```swift
let labelFontSize = 17

func setScore(_ newScore: Int) {
    labelNode.attributedText = .init(
        string: String(newScore),
        attributes: [
            .font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(
                ofSize: labelFontSize,
                weight: .bold
            ),
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        ]
    )
}
```

Next - fix the position of `SKLabelNode` inside `SKShapeNode` (or any other rectangle):

```
func adjustLabelToFitRect(labelNode: SKLabelNode, rect: CGRect) {
    labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .baseline
    labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center

    // Originally this function worked with labelNode.frame.height
    // But it depends on fontSize, so I decided to use it as a base
    var labelHeightShift = (labelFontSize - 1) / 2.0
    labelHeightShift -= 0.8  // empirical pixel perfect observation

    // Move the SKLabelNode to the center of the rectangle.
    labelNode.position = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY - labelHeightShift)
}
```

Note that we are setting `verticalAlignmentMode` to `.baseline`. Because of that, we need to calculate `labelHeightShift` by ourselves.

Yeah, the code is a little dirty with `0.8` and other constants. But I haven't found a better solution.

I hope that helps someone.